# Neo4j Cyper: Indexing numeric field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `Neo4j` with `Cyper query`

My requirement:

How to index a numeric field of node in optimised way.

My Person Node as,

```
year_month  --> 2014.1 or 2014.2 or 2014.3 and so on 
desc
status
```

Presently indexed as,
    CREATE INDEX ON :Person(year_month)

1. Is there any optimised way to do index specially for numeric (Using Cyper queries) ?

i found somewhere as

```
new ValueContext( 1999 ).indexNumeric() for indexing
```

2. whether the above is possible to use it in `Cyper queries` ?

Answer (score 1):

Indexes on properties and label only apply to equality comparisons in the `WHERE` clause in Cypher: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-use-index-with-where

To make use of the index on the `year_month` property, you must specify an exact match for optimized lookups.

```
WITH 2014 as year, 5 as month
WITH ((year * 12) + month) as year_month
MATCH (p:Person { year_month: year_month })
RETURN p
```

Here are some tips for optimizing your Cypher queries for both range queries and exact match queries on `year_month`.

Instead of floating point values, convert your year and month to an integer.

Conversion to: `monthIndex = (year * 12) + month`

Conversion from: `year = (monthIndex / 12), month = (monthIndex % 12)`

Create node with a compound index for the properties `month` and `year` as `year_month`:

```
WITH 2014 as year, 5 as month
CREATE (michael:Person { 
    name: "Michael", 
    year_month: ((year * 12) + month), 
    year: year, 
    month: month })
```

Create your index on `year_month` property of the label `Person`:

```
 CREATE INDEX ON :Person(year_month)
```

This approach allows you to query by range.

Query the node by range between `5/2013` and `5/2014`:

```
WITH 2013 as year_from, 5 as month_from,
     2014 as year_to, 5 as month_to
WITH ((year_from * 12) + month_from) as date_from, 
     ((year_to * 12) + month_to) as date_to
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.year_month >= date_from AND p.year_month <= date_to
RETURN p
```